# Como colocar parametro opcional em Reactjs

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou precisando enviar uma requisição, mas tem um parametro que é opcional, e só devo enviar com uma condição.
Está assim:

```
const [blocoSelect, setBlocoSelect] = useState("nenhum");
        params: {
          initial_date: dateRange.startDate._d,
          final_date: dateRange.endDate._d,
          order: isMaisAntigasSelected ? 'DESC' : 'ASC',
          condo_id: condoSelect,
          blocs: isManuBlocs,
          areas: isManuArea,
          // bloc_name: opcional
        }
```

Esse ***bloc_name*** é opcional, ele só vai se meu ***blocoSelect*** for diferente de nenhum, tentei algo como:

```
        params: {
          initial_date: dateRange.startDate._d,
          final_date: dateRange.endDate._d,
          order: isMaisAntigasSelected ? 'DESC' : 'ASC',
          condo_id: condoSelect,
          blocs: isManuBlocs,
          areas: isManuArea,
          {
            blocoSelect!=="nenhum" &&
           bloc_name: opcional  }
        }
```

Mas vi que a sintaxe estava errada e não sei como corrigir

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo arrumando o seu exemplo (seguindo sua linha de raciocínio), o resultado nunca seria `undefined` - retornaria `false` como valor, ou seja, o campo sempre seria enviado. Veja abaixo:

```js
const addParam = false;
const params = {
  key: addParam && 'valor',
  key2: !addParam && 'valor',
};

console.log(params);
```

Para colocar um atributo opcional num objeto, você pode fazer uso de um operador ternário como fez em `order`:

```js
const addParam = false;
const params = {
  key: addParam ? 'valor' : undefined,
  key2: !addParam ? 'valor' : undefined,
};

console.log(params);
```